# Can rootkit work while PC's in sleep mode?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, malware, wake-on-lan

If a PC has rootkit, when it goes into sleep mode, can rootkit do anything to it? Meaning steal data, open programs while it's sleeping? Assuming Wake On LAN option is completly disabled so it can't wake computer from sleep mode.

Answer (score 2):

This question may be better answered on security.stackexchange.

I posit that this would be a very hard ask and impractical, but not impossible in all cases.  Many PC's (albeit more commonly/accessibly in servers) include Baseboard Management Controllers (ie BMC's) which are small, low-power embedded computers which have pretty full access to the computer, and importantly, operate when the computer is in sleep mode.

If the rootkit can take control of the BMC it can use this to control the computer even in sleep mode, although in so doing it may wake the computer up whereby defeating their stealth.  I would posit that for this reason it is unlikely to be heavily used to do this except by very targetted, advanced threat actors.

Comment: Also look at Intel Active Management Technology which is very similar- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology but built into more consumer devices.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine#Ring_-3 may also be useful to you.